# VTK/Paraview Programmable source for spheres with specific radius

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

I want to visualize a list of spheres, each one with its specific radius. I had the same problem with lines but I solved it with @Nico vuaille's  https://stackoverflow.com/users/10219194/nico-vuaille answer as:

```
import vtk
from random import uniform
points = vtk.vtkPoints()
lines = vtk.vtkCellArray()
widths = vtk.vtkDoubleArray()
widths.SetName("width")

for i in range(60):
  pt1 = points.InsertNextPoint(uniform(0, 100), uniform(0, 100), 0)
  pt2 = points.InsertNextPoint(uniform(0, 100), uniform(0, 100), 0)
  w = uniform(0,3)
  widths.InsertNextValue(w)
  widths.InsertNextValue(w)
  lines.InsertNextCell(2, [pt1, pt2])

output.SetPoints(points)
output.GetPointData().AddArray(widths)
output.SetLines(lines)
```

However, I'm not able to do the same for spheres since I can't find a "sphere" filter.
Thanks in advance for you help,
Best Regards,
Hamid Rajabi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ParaView, you can use the `Glyph` Filter. It display a predefined geometry on given points.
You can use predefined shape (such as sphere). Or you can also use your own geometry by using `Glyph with custom Source` instead.